# AWS Load Balancer Git Clone error over SSH Port

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-elb

#### Summary

We created a EC2 Instance and install Gitlab, after that we created an Application Load Balancer, we configure it with a subdomain over HTTPS, all works fine, we created a new repositorie, add our ssh-keys, if we clone the HTTPS its all ok, but over SSH we can't clone it for this error:

```
`ssh: connect to host gitlab.our.subdomain port 22: Connection refused`
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Created a new EC2 and install Gitlab
2. Configure Gitlab:

   - external_url 'https://gitlab.our.subdomain/'
   - nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
   - nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
   - nginx['listen_port'] = 80
   - nginx['listen_https'] = false
   - "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
   - "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
     3.- Set permissions over EC2 and ALB
     [image: Captura_de_pantalla_2018-10-16_a_la_s__12.17.27]

[image: Captura_de_pantalla_2018-10-16_a_la_s__12.17.19]

#### What is the current *bug* behavior?

````
```
git clone git@gitlab.our.subdomain:ucrea/ucrea_portal.git
Cloning into 'ucrea_portal'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.realhost.cloud port 22: Connection refused
```
````

#### What is the expected *correct* behavior?

Clone de project over SSH

#### Relevant logs

````
```
git clone git@gitlab.realhost.cloud:ucrea/ucrea_portal.git
Cloning into 'ucrea_portal'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.our.dubdomain port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```
````

#### Details of package version

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

````
```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                         Version                             Architecture                        Description
+++-============================================================-===================================-===================================-==============================================================================================================================
ii  gitlab-ce                                                    11.3.4-ce.0                         amd64                               GitLab Community Edition (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)
un  gitlab-ee                                                    <none>                              <none>                              (no description available)
```
````

#### Environment details

- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Installation Target, remove incorrect values:

  - EC2
  - VM: AWS
  - Other: Application Load Balancer
- Installation Type, remove incorrect values:

  - New Installation
  - Upgrade from version 11.3.4-ce.0
  - Other: 11.3.4-ce.0

#### Configuration details

- external_url 'https://gitlab.our.subdomain/'
- nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
- nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
- nginx['listen_port'] = 80
- nginx['listen_https'] = false
- "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
- "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"

Comment: What are the security group settings? Have you opened ssh port 22 on the ELB?

Comment: May be try alternate ssh instead port 22 https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ulises
Use a classic elastic load balancer allowing ingress ports 80, 22 with security groups.

Comment: You are right, seems like ALB is 7 layer, so Classic Load Balancer allows this.

Comment: We are facing the similar issue with bitbucket, where we can establish connections properly but we cannot be able to clone the repo, since we are using application load balancer. Moving forward we cannot create classic load balancer, can any one guide me what would be the correct fix for this now ?